# ImportError no module named calendar

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I have installed Python 2.7.5 on my Windows 7 host. I want to use the CalendarCtrl widget which is part of 'wx.calendar' module. When I try to import calendar I get the following error:

```
>>> import wx  
>>> import wx.calendar  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
ImportError: No module named calendar
```

On Linux host I have no problem with the

```
import wx.calendar
```

statement. Any help to resolve the issue is much appreciated.

Comment: what's your version of wxPython?

Comment: @Xuan - I have installed version 2.8.12.1. When I execute the statement 'print wx.version()' on the Windows host it complains "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'version'". On Linux host I get '2.8.12.1 (gtk2-unicode).

Comment: i think there is something wrong with your wxpython installation. perhaps try reinstalling it?

Comment: @Xuan - Thank you very much. This happens on two different Windows host. BTW, how did you conclude that there is a problem with my installation? Does it by any chance work on your Windows host?

Comment: Check your sys.path list and make sure that there are no ancient versions of wxPython installed and being found first on the sys.path.  Or there could be some module named wx that is not part of wxPython that is being found.  The wx.version function has been available in all wxPython releases for many years now.  Or doing `import wx; print wx.__file__` can also tell you where the bogus wx is being imported from.

Comment: @RobinDunn - Thank you very much. I am not sure what I am looking for in 'sys.path'. I cannot enclose the output here because of length restrictions. Here is the output for 'print wx.__file__': E:\Install\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-1.0.0-py2.7.egg\wx.pyc

Comment: I found the culprit. The 'sys.path' had 'E:\\Install\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-1.0.0-py2.7.egg', and 'E:\\Install\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode']. I renamed the 'wx-1.0.0-py2.7.egg' and voila things are working better then before. Thanks for all the pointers so far.